# Is there a practical way to reuse a set of test methods against different stubs in the Microsoft Unit Test Framework?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am using the Microsoft Unit Test framework under Visual Studio 2012 to test a C# class that represents a data access layer towards a database of some kind.

In order to be able to unit test it, I have created a stub that the class uses instead of said database.
My test class has the following structure:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests {

    MyStub stub;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeContext() { // Construct stub  }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanupContext() { // Dispose stub }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1() { ... }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2() { ... }

    ...
}
```

It works fine.

I would now like to write a second test class that performs the same tests against a different stub, therefore I'd like to reuse the code, but I'm unable to achieve this through inheritance (inheriting `UnitTests` and overriding both `InitializeContext()` and `CleanupContext()`) because the `TestMethod` attribute appears not to be inheritable.

Is there a practical way to achieve this at all? If so, which one?

Comment: Are you adding the `TestClass` attribute to the top of the derived classes?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have a set of tests that belong to a "test set" that you want to run against in different environments.

I personally solve that by implementing the tests outside of the actual tests, and call the externally implemented tests with parameters:

```html
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests1 {

    MyStub stub;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeContext() { // Construct stub  }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanupContext() { // Dispose stub }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1() { StubTests.TestMyStub(stub); }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2() { StubTests.TestMyStub2(stub); }

    ...
}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTests2 {

    MyStub stub;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeContext() { // Construct stub  }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanupContext() { // Dispose stub }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1() { StubTests.TestMyStub(stub); }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2() { StubTests.TestMyStub2(stub); }

    ...
}
```

The "StubTests" class does not use any annotations and refers to outside dependencies using the parameters in the functions (handing over the stub for example).